# Can my professor figure out the framework of my website?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Well we have some projects in our uni about creating HTML/CSS/JavaScript/PHP webpages, basic stuff, we then compress and email the files to them.

Now they want us to create the websites with Notepad++ and they specifically state "other frameworks are NOT allowed"... but I want to use JetBrains PhpStorm for obvious reasons!

**The question is:** is there anyway they can tell if I have used PhpStorm? Is there any signature on the code/file extension or something? If yes, how can I hide it?

Comment: Do you mean IDE or framework? Notepad and PHPStorm aren't frameworks afaik. Also, probably off topic.

Comment: Wow, that's a terrible restriction. I can understand wanting students to start at the lowest level possible, but this is pretty silly and has nothing to do with the real world. Are you sure they're not just recommending N++ as an *editor*, but are restricting the use of *frameworks* like Bootstrap, Codeigniter et al?

Comment: PhpStorm is an IDE. If you wish (in the scope of the actual question) -- advanced text editor. It's not a framework (which is used by CSS/JS/PHP part). Now: **1)** Can they tell what CSS/JS/PHP framework you are using? If its among more-or-less popular ones -- yes. **2)** Can they tell what IDE/editor you have used -- Yes and No. If you send them whole project folder (developed in PhpStorm) -- yes .. as it contains `.idea` subfolder -- that's your project settings. If you delete that folder -- then No (except some possible traces in .gitignore or similar specific files).

Comment: So -- if editor (PhpStorm in your case) is the issue -- just do not include `.idea` subfolder into your final archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

This is probably an exercise to teach you to look for errors yourself etc., rather than 
relying on automated tools.

If it is basic stuff, Notepad++ should be more than sufficient, though.